# How to implement something like the strategy pattern in scala

Tags: scala

I would like to achieve something akin to the strategy pattern in scala without resorting to pattern matching with a long list of case statements. Here is roughly what I have in mind:

```
trait HandlerTrait {
   def handlerA(...): Unit
   def handlerB(...): Unit
}

SomeClass1 extends HandlerTrait {
   override def handlerA(...) {...}
   override def handlerB(...) {...}
}

SomeClass2 extends HandlerTrait {
   override def handlerA(...) {...}
   override def handlerB(...) {...}
}

object MyApp extends App {
   // 1. define bindings for these implementations
   val myBindings = Map(x -> someClass1, y -> someClass2)

   // 2. Such that implementation of someMethod targeting handlerA implementations could look like this:
   def someMethod(object: ObjectType): Unit = {
      myBindings.get(object.x) match {
        case Some(entry) => entry.handlerA(object)
        case None => ()
      }
   }
}
```

A few more things:

1. I don't know how many SomeClassXXX I will have. I will add as needed
   to provide customizations on how to handle A/B/C ...
2. Given a key, I want to dispatch to the correct class and execute the targeted handler.

Is there a better more concise way of achieving this in scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one way to reduce boilerplate is to use type system rather than inheritance. For instance, if your handler is of type `T => Unit` then any function that satisfies this type can be a handler, there is no need to officially declare `HandlerTrait` and even `someMethod`.

Whether to use a `Map` or `case`s to map from a key to a handler is up to you. Both can be extended to handle new cases.

Here is an example to sum up what I'm proposing:

```
val currentlyDefinedStrategies: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = {
  case "1" => println(1)
  case "2" => println(2)
}

val newStrategies: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = {
  case "3" => println(3)
}

val defaultStrategy: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = {
  case _ => println("default")
}
```

And usage:

```
scala> currentlyDefinedStrategies("1")
1

scala> currentlyDefinedStrategies("3")
scala.MatchError: 3 (of class java.lang.String) ...

scala> currentlyDefinedStrategies.orElse(newStrategies)("3")
3

scala> currentlyDefinedStrategies.orElse(newStrategies)("4")
scala.MatchError: 4 (of class java.lang.String)

scala> currentlyDefinedStrategies.orElse(newStrategies).orElse(defaultStrategy)("4")
default
```

You can achieve similar pattern with `Map` or using other FP techniques. The main point is to keep the most relevant code and get rid of boilerplate. Of course, `HandlerTrait` might be useful to you for structuring your code and thinking in terms of classes rather than functions, but the idea is the same.

See also: https://pavelfatin.com/design-patterns-in-scala/#strategy

The above example is a bit simplified and you actually want to pass parameters to handler (`println` in our case). Here is how:

```
val currentlyDefinedStrategies: Int => PartialFunction[String, Unit] = (x) => { 
  case "1" => println("1: " + x)
  case "2" => println("2: " + x)
  case _ => println("default: " + x)
}
```

You can fix the argument without choosing a strategy:

```
scala> val noStrategy = currentlyDefinedStrategies(1)
noStrategy: PartialFunction[String,Unit] = <function1>
```

... and provide strategy afterwards:

```
scala> noStrategy("1")
1: 1
```

Or apply the strategy right away:

```
scala> currentlyDefinedStrategies(1)("1")
1: 1
```

You can also decide on your strategy first and then pass an argument:

```
val currentlyDefinedStrategies: PartialFunction[String, Int => Unit] = { 
  case "1" => x => println("1: " + x)
  case "2" => x => println("2: " + x)
  case _ => x => println("default: " + x)
}

scala> val handlerWithChosenStrategy = currentlyDefinedStrategies("1")
handlerWithChosenStrategy: Int => Unit = $anonfun$1$$Lambda$1374/666224848@59a9f3eb

scala> handlerWithChosenStrategy(1)
1: 1
```

I think the point is that FP is so rich and flexible that strategy pattern is really not a thing. It's basically just some function type that suits your convenience like `type Strategy[T, -A, +B] = PartialFunction[T, A => B]`. Example:

```
scala> type Strategy[T, -A, +B] = PartialFunction[T, A => B]
defined type alias Strategy

val currentlyDefinedStrategies: Strategy[String, Int, Unit] = {
  case "1" => x => println("1: " + x)
  case "2" => x => println("2: " + x)
  case _ => x => println("default: " + x)
}
currentlyDefinedStrategies: Strategy[String,Int,Unit] = <function1>

scala> currentlyDefinedStrategies("1")(1)
1: 1
```

A more advanced concept would be an Expression Problem ([here](http://izmailoff.github.io/programming%20languages/expression-problem/)) where you need to extend both the operations you can do on types as well as adding new types.

Comment: This is indeed helpful. Thank you.